# fork with Ruby 1.8 and Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, fork

I'm using ruby 1.8.7 patchlevel 302 and I'm working on a Windows xp system. 
I have to start an external process that needs to react on user input. The process doesn't react if I use threads, so I tried using fork. With fork the external process reacts on the user input but it executes more than just the fork block. For example

```
fork do
  puts 'child'
end
puts 'parent'
Process.wait
puts 'done'
```

produces the following output on my machine:

```
parent
child
parent
done
done
```

As you can see 'done' and 'parent' is printed twice. What can I do to make the child execute only its block and not more? (I can't switch to Ruby 1.9 because of some gems)

Comment: are you using cygwin ruby? how does fork work?

Comment: how does fork work ? are you using win32 lib ?

Comment: You need the win32-process gem. On ruby 1.8.7 you need version 0.6.6 (at least for windows 8)

Answer (score 2):

Like that:

```
if child = fork
  puts 'parent'
  Process.wait
  puts 'done'
else
  puts 'child'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a little makeshift. It works like its supposed to be when I add Process.kill(1, 0) at the end of the child block. But I think it's not the best solution. So I'd still be happy if someone knows a real solution.

Comment: @rogerdpack I'm using the win32-process gem that implements process methods that are not available in default ruby in Windows. I do not use cygwin. I must admit that I don't exactly know how fork works. I had a look at the sample code in a Ruby book and I'd hoped that the gem would work like the Linux Process.fork method.

Comment: Makeshift, part II: Because the hole parent process is kind of copied, there are maybe parts at the beginning that shouldn't be run by the child. To find out if a child process is running, check the last argument (ARGV[ARGV.size-1] if ARGV.size > 0). If it is a child process, it is "child#x".

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need `Process.exit!` before you end your fork.

```
fork do
  puts 'child'
  Process.exit!
end
puts 'parent'
Process.wait
puts 'done'
```