# Using fork in Windows with Ruby

Tags: ruby

When I call `Kernel.fork()` on Windows, I get this error:

```
!! Unexpected error while processing request: fork() function is unimplemented on this machine
```

Is there an alternative way to fork while on Windows?

Answer (score 7):

Try `spawn()` - it's implemented for windows.

Answer (score 4):

While the Windows OS does not support fork, the [win32-process gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/win32-process) appears to support a substitute.    Apparently there are some differences from the unix version though, see this question: [fork with Ruby 1.8 and Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3853250/10396)

Answer (score 2):

The usual way to get a faithful fork emulation on Windows is to install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) and run with its library.   In this case you will need to install a second Ruby, this time from the Cygwin package.

Answer (score 0):

As DigitalRoss mentioned, [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com) is [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posix) compliant, and has fork.

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> Kernel.fork()
=> 4512
irb(main):002:0> => nil
irb(main):002:0> quit

$ uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-5.1 dumbopc 1.7.17(0.262/5/3) 2012-10-19 14:39 i686 Cygwin

$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p385 (2013-02-06 revision 39114) [i386-cygwin]
```

You may have to use the [Cygwin Ports](http://cygwinports.org/) mirror to find the Ruby package.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 has the Windows Subsystem for Linux feature that you can install.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/install-win10

This will allow you to leverage one of the Unix Distro apps in the Windows store to install a bash shell. You can then run your app in a Linux environment, effectively enabling Fork()