# Exiting ruby in subshell without killing parent

Tags: ruby, termination, subshell

I have Ruby programA that calls Ruby programB with:

```
 system("ruby programB.rb <parameters>")
```

Under certain conditions, I want programB to terminate its operation (and the associated subshell) but allow programA to continue on to the next set of parameters.

However, `exit()` and `abort()` kill both the subshell and the parent, and I am unable to get `Process.kill("SIGTERM",0)` to work in programB (unfortunately, this is on Windows).  I'm running ruby 1.9.2.

How can I terminate programB without also killing programA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that works reliably for me is this:

```
kill -INT $$
```

It reliably kills the script and only the script, even if it was source'd from the command line. Note that I'm running GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0); I can't recall if this works on bash 3.x

Answer (score 3):

If the regular `system` call isn't cutting it, the usual way is to do something like this:

```
pid = fork do
  exec("ruby programB.rb ...")
end

kill("SIGTERM", pid)
```

The `fork` operation gives you a process identifier you can kill. `system` will block until the child process returns, so any call to `kill` in the parent process will affect only the parent process.

Unfortunately there's no `fork` in Windows, but there are [alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998130/using-fork-in-windows-with-ruby) that achieve the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to alternatives for Windows; I've made a note of that for the future.

Answer (score 2):

`exit()` and `abort()` don't kill the parent, at least not on Mac OS, and Linux in my experience.

Try saving this as `abort.rb`:

```
puts RUBY_VERSION
puts `date`
puts 'aborting'
abort
```

and this as `exit.rb`:

```
puts RUBY_VERSION
puts `date`
puts 'exiting'
exit
```

Then save this as `test.rb` in the same directory and run it:

```
puts `ruby exit.rb`
puts `ruby abort.rb`
```

On my system I see:

```
1.9.3
Fri Dec 21 22:17:12 MST 2012
exiting
1.9.3
Fri Dec 21 22:17:12 MST 2012
aborting
```

They do exit the currently running script in the sub-shell, which then exits because it's not a log-in shell, and could set a return status which is important to the calling program, but I have yet to see them kill the parent.

If you need to capture STDERR, using backticks or `%x` won't work. I'd recommend using `Open3.capture3` for simplicity if you need to know what status code was returned, or whether STDERR returned anything.

Comment: FYI, I needed `date /t` for windows, but other than that it worked as you expected, so I went back to go over my code yet again. Finally found a typo '\' instead of '|' which solved the problem. Thanks!